# Excel add-ins | implement sign in flow using ribbon

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, office365api

I am using Office.js, javascript and react to create excel add-ins. Wants to implement single sign-in flow using ribbon button. Once user successfully sign in then only wants to show task pane to user.

1. Sign in button present in ribbon.
2. I do have third party URL like below and if user authenticate successfully it redirect to given application URL.
   https://google.com?response_type=abc&client_Id=xyz&**redirect_uri=https://application-url-to-redirect**
3. Above URL opens username/password window and upon providing valid details its redirect user to application URL and then task pane should open.

please help/suggest how can i implement this functionality. Please guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure the add-in to use a [shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime).
2. Use an [Add-in command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) to configure a button.
3. The button should call code in a [function file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands).
4. The function file code should [use the Office dialog to authenticate to Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api).
5. When the authentication completes, the code in the dialog should [send a message to the parent function file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#send-information-from-the-dialog-box-to-the-host-page).
6. Code in the function file should [close the dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#closing-the-dialog-box) and then [show the task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/excel/show-hide-add-in).

Comment: Thanks Rick, will go through the provided links.

Comment: created new question, can you please help on same.             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485738/office-js-implement-single-sign-in-excel-add-in  Thanks in advance.