# Office.js | implement single sign in excel add-in

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, office-addins, office365api

I am using Office.js, javascript and react to create excel add-ins. Wants to implement single sign-in flow using ribbon button. Once user successfully sign in then only wants to show task pane to user.

1. I have configured add-in using shared runtime(manifest.xml)
2. I have added Login command in ribbon and executing action from manifest file by using below code.

> Below is the Action from manifest file. 'btnlogin' function gets executed on click of login icon from ribbon

```
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <TaskpaneId>DataDirectId</TaskpaneId>
    <FunctionName>btnlogin</FunctionName>
    <SourceLocation resid="LGButton.Url" />
</Action>
```

using Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync() inside btnlogin function and passing "oauth2" authorization URL to dialog. URL is on different HOST. And if pass open dialog as i-frame then receiving X-FRAME-OPTIONS = DENY in response header due to it authorization URL Refused to display on I-frame. If i dont pass displayInIframe then authorization URL opens. Also i added authorization URL host inside "AppDomain".

Authorization URL opens username/pass window inside dialog and once user pass correct user name/pass authorization URL redirects to provided path. e.g below is my Authorization URL which i'm trying to open inside dialog:
https://google.com?response_type=abc&client_Id=xyz&**redirect_uri=https://application-url-to-redirect**

Please help to implement below scenario:
**On entering of correct username/pass wants to close the dialog and open redirection_URI on task pane.**

We are using hash router in our application.

Do i need to use any react-oidc or passport-auth lib ? please suggest and help for implementing same.